# Minimize the number of page faults by loop interchange

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, page-fault

Assume page size is 1024 words and each row is stored in one page.
If the OS allocates 512 frames for a program and uses LRU page replacement algorithm,
What will be the number of page faults in the following programs?

```
int A[][] = new int[1024][1024];

Program 1:
for (j = 0; j < A.length; j++)
    for (i = 0; i < A.length; i++) 
        A[i][j] = 0;

Program 2:
for (i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < A.length; j++) 
        A[i][j] = 0;
```

I assume that bringing the pages by row is better than bringing by column, however I cannot support my claim. Can you help me to calculate # of page faults?

Answer (score 0):

One way to answer this is by simulation.   You could change your loops to output the address of the assignment rather than setting it to zero:

```
printf("%p\n", &A[i][j]);
```

Then, write a second program that simulates page placement, so it would do something like:

```
    uintptr_t h;
    uintptr_t work[NWORKING_SET] = {0};
    int lru = 0;
    int fault = 0;
    while (gethex(&h)) {
        h /= pagesize;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < NWORKING_SET && work[i] != h; i++) {
        }
        if (i == NWORKING_SET) {
              work[lru] = h;
              fault++;
              lru = (lru+1) % NWORKING_SET;
        }
   }
   printf("%d\n", fault);
```

With that program in place, you can try multiple traversal strategies.   PS: my lru just happens to work; I'm sure you can do much better.

Comment: What is the NWORKING_SET value? Is it predefined in a library?

Comment: I think you said 512 in your original post.   Working Set is the colloquial name for the number of active pages a process uses.  Again, you can do much better than this little sketch.

Answer (score 0):

For the second program; the CPU accesses the first `int` in a row causing a page fault, then accesses the other `int`s in the row while the page is already present. This means that (if the rows start on page boundaries) you'll get a page fault per row, plus probably one when the program's code is first started, plus probably another when the program's stack is first used (and one more if the array isn't aligned on a page boundary); which probably works out to 1026 or 1027 page faults.

For the first program; the CPU accesses the first `int` in a row causing a page fault; but by the time it accesses the second `int` in that same row the page has been evicted (become "least recently used" and replaced with a different page). This means that you'll get 1024*1024 page faults while accessing the array (plus one for program's code, stack, etc). That probably works out to 1048578 page faults (as long as the start of the array is aligned to "`sizeof(int)`").

However; this all assumes that the compiler failed to optimize anything. In reality it's extremely likely that any compiler that is worth using would have transformed both programs into something a little more like "`memset(array, 0, sizeof(int)*1024*1024);` that does consecutive writes (possibly writing multiple `int`s in a single larger write if underlying CPU supports larger writes). This implies that both programs would take probably cause 1026 or 1027 page faults.